# JavaRx on ErrorReturn return the different type

Tags: java, rx-java

Observable is tied to a type. When onError I don't want to return the same type but different Object. Example Response object with status=400. How to achieve this?

```
public class Test{
    @Autowired
    private Server server;

    public Response getResponse(String id){
        Observable<Person>  personObservable = server.get(id);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        personObservable.onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, Person>() {
        @Override
         public Person call(Throwable throwable) {
              //I would like to return a HttpResponseObject taking the message
              //from throwable error information how to do it?
              // How to use Transform() in this case ?
              return null;
         }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executorService)).subscribe(new Action1<Person>() {
            // If i use subscribe() will it be not async?
            // I think subscribe still run on the main thread so is this
            // subscribeOn use fine ?
            @Override
            public void call(Person person) {
                // Is this fine to use the list outside the observable ?
                persons.add(person);
            }
       });
        Response r = new Response;
        r.addPersons(persons);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks weird trying to do so, because your observable is meant to return `Person` objects. How could your subscriber react when it will receive `HttpResponseObject`s while it's supposed to get `Person`s via `void call (Person)` ?

Comment: There is Observable.Transformer<T,R> available but I am not sure how to use it in case of errorReturn scenario, where you need to return object type then observable was initialized.

Comment: well, if evey event is meant to be transformed into an `HttpResponseObject`, then you could use an operation (like `map`) to transform Person to HttpResponseObject, then add the `errorReturn`operator to handle your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onErrorResumeNext`:

```
Observable<Person> personObservable = ...;
return personObservable
             .toList()
             .map(persons -> new Response(persons))
             .onErrorResumeNext(error -> new Response(error.getMessage())
             .toBlocking().single();
```